# Get a list of all the colors labels from color attribute that are currently not assigned to any products

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I get a list of colors label from the color attribute that are currently not assigned to any products in my site?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to find color which is not assign in any color via SQL query as below.

```
SELECT V.value FROM eav_attribute_option_value AS V 
JOIN eav_attribute_option AS O ON O.option_id = V.option_id 
WHERE O.attribute_id = '94' AND 
O.option_id NOT IN (
    SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_int 
    WHERE attribute_id = '94' AND 
    value IS NOT NULL
)
```

Where attribute id 94 is color attribute id from `eav_attribute` table.
If you want to check via code than first get list of all attributes & check product collection by each one.